# How do I use wget (or any other downloading command) when using fish (friendly interactive shell)?

Tags: download, wget, fish

I'm trying to download some files from a website, git specifically. I can't quite figure out how to use the download command. wget isn't a command in fish, and their documentation didn't have anything explaining another web downloading command.

Thanks in advance, and I'm really sorry if this is an ignorant question. I did do my best to sort it out beforehand.

Edit: The command I'm using is this:

```
wget -O ~/.vimrc http://github.com/lucasoman/Conf/raw/master/.vimrc
```

But wget isn't a command in fish.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you be more specific?

Comment: If a program with a specific name is in your $PATH, fish should just call it - what does `type wget` say? It is also possible that you set your $PATH wrong, which is a list in fish - the output of `echo "p "$PATH` (mind the missing space) should show you how many elements $PATH has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've read of the documentation, fish is like other UN*X shells, in that there's no notion of "a command in fish".  A command in a UN*X shell is either

- one of a small set of built-in commands;
- an executable program or script, with the same file name as the command, in a directory in your search path;
- in some shells, an alias or shell function.

[Your search path is in the PATH variable in fish](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path), as it is in most other UN*X shells.  The command `echo $PATH` will print it.  If the directory containing the wget executable image isn't in any of the directories listed by `echo $PATH`, fish won't find it.